# Uncaught RangeError: Item index is out of range error in Sqlite Query Results phonegap

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print the results to my Select statement into a list in my HTML(phonegap). I am using Sqlite (This is a requirement for the project) to store my tables.

My Select Statement:

```
        function queryDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT servidor, banco, usuario, senha FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
    }

  function querySuccess(tx, results) {

        var row = results.rows.item(0);

          $("#servidor").val(row['servidor']);
          $("#banco").val(row['banco']);
          $("#usuario").val(row['usuario']);
          $("#senha").val(row['senha']);
```

When I run my code, it properly displays all the records for the DEMO table in the list, but I am getting an "Uncaught RangeError: Item index is out of range" error on this line:

```
      $("#servidor").val(row['servidor']);
      $("#banco").val(row['banco']);
      $("#usuario").val(row['usuario']);
      $("#senha").val(row['senha']);
```

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking if the variable row has a value before trying to blindly access data within. from the looks of it you may not have any data in the row variable or at least not ever piece you're trying to get to. You need to be using development tools in either chrome, firefox, Ie, it doesn't matter you just need to be using them if you are going to writing javascript. You will get errors.

```
//this statement may be throwing the error, you should be debugging this code in a browser using the development tools.
          var row = results.rows.item(0);
         if(row.length > 0){
                  $("#servidor").val(row['servidor']);
                  $("#banco").val(row['banco']);
                  $("#usuario").val(row['usuario']);
                  $("#senha").val(row['senha'])
    }else{
      alert('row has no data');
    }
```